# Connect to SFTP using PowerShell and download files

Tags: powershell, sftp

I am aware that there is a similar question asked previously but the solutions primarily focus on using WinSCP. I'm fairly new to SFTP and PowerShell as well, and I need help downloading files from an SFTP server onto my application server.

I believe that the Posh-SSH module can help with establishing an SFTP connection, but most code I have seen until now involves uploading files onto the SFTP server, not downloading from... would appreciate any advice!

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`Get-SFTPItem` cmdlet](https://github.com/darkoperator/Posh-SSH/blob/master/docs/Get-SFTPItem.md) (`Get-SFTPFile` in older versions):

```
$remotePath = "/remote/path/file.ext"
$localPath = "C:\local\path\file.ext"
Get-SFTPItem -SessionId $sessionId -Path $remotePath -Destination $localPath
```

---

WinSCP will work too though:
[Download files from SFTP server using PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46660545/850848)